# JPA Save list of dates

Tags: mapping, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, glassfish-3

We must save a entity which holds a list of date objects. The list is annotated as follows:

```
@ElementCollection
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
public List<Date> dates {
   return dates;
}
```

This works but the dates are mapped with varchar type in database. Is there another way to store a collection of dates in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is odd, it should use the DATE type.  I assume you are using EclipseLink to generate your DDL?

You could set the column definition using the @Column annotation to set the type explicitly.

(also try the latest EclipseLink release, and if it still fails log a bug).